# Match email with existing email in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have create wizard control. User will enter user name, email and password to register. Then they need to login after register.After user hit login button, there will be a textbox for user to insert their registered email before. They will only redirected to Home page if their email is matched with their registered email. If not, they need to re-type the email again. How to do that?

Comment: search google first..there are lot of ideas you can get with googleing..or post some code of yours..what have your tried yet..

Comment: @Clarify Seeker Since you are new to this, Please post your code or SQL if any, that you have tried yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will return 1 if it finds a match, otherwise it will return zero. `Password` is not included since  you've mentioned that it is already on the second page (*meaning the user successfully entered correct username and password*)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tablename
WHERE userName = 'value' AND
      email = 'email'
```